# Calculus with objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that contains 2 fields: `day_active` and `day_inactive`. (the object is in the javascript snippet below)

And what I want to obtain is another object that is based on this formula:

> count(day_active (on date x))-count(day_inactive (on date x)

```
{
    {
        "date" : "2019-09-19",
        "type" : "groupC",
        "count" : 2.0 // (5.0 - 3.0) - how many groupC were on day_active(2019-09-19) minus how many groupC were on day_inactive(2019-09-19) 
    },
    {
        "date" : "2019-09-19",
        "type" : "groupW",
        "count" : -2.0 // (3.0 - 5.0)
    },
    {
        "date" : "2019-09-11",
        "type" : "groupW",
        "count" : -2.0 // (8.0 - 10.0)
    },
    {
        "date" : "2019-10-08",
        "type" : "groupW",
        "count" : 7.0 // (7.0 - 0.0)
    }
}
```

I tried this code but is not taking all the cases and the result is incomplete:

```js
let items = {
    "day_inactive" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-19",
            "type" : "groupC",
            "count" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-11",
            "type" : "groupW",
            "count" : 10.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-19",
            "type" : "groupW",
            "count" : 5.0
        },
        {
            "date" : "2019-10-07",
            "type" : "groupW",
            "count" : 9.0
        },
        {
            "date" : "2019-10-05",
            "type" : "groupW",
            "count" : 3.0
        },
    ],
    "day_active" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-11",
            "type" : "groupW",
            "count" : 8.0
        },
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-19",
            "type" : "groupW",
            "count" : 3.0
        },
        {
            "date" : "2019-10-08",
            "type" : "groupW",
            "count" : 7.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2019-09-19",
            "type" : "groupC",
            "count" : 5.0
        }
    ]
}

let auxObj = {}

for (let i = 0; i < items.day_active.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < items.day_inactive.length; j++) {
    if (items.day_active[i].date == items.day_inactive[j].date && items.day_active[i].type == items.day_inactive[j].type) {
      // console.log("yes")
      auxObj.date = items.day_active[i].date
      auxObj.type = items.day_active[i].type
      auxObj.count = items.day_active[i].count - items.day_inactive[j].count
    }
  }
}

console.log(auxObj)
```

How can I solve this in a simple way? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Any abscence of active(data) or inactive(data) should be considered a 0 right?

Comment: @MKougiouris yes, you are right

Comment: You can't have a JS object with nested objects without properties, I'm assuming that what you want is a new array with those new objects inside, correct?

Comment: @DavidFontes yes, a whole new array that contains those objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow along the comments for explanation...

```js
// let's create an empty object
let output = {};

// and start copying active days...
for (const obj of items.day_active) {
    // the following `key` is just for grouping purposes...
    const key = `${obj.date}-${obj.type}`;
    output[key] = { ...obj };
}

// Now let's look at inactive days...
for (const obj of items.day_inactive) {
    // the following `key` is just for grouping purposes...
    const key = `${obj.date}-${obj.type}`;

    // is this the first time we're looking at this `date-type`? let's add it with 0 count
    if (!output[key]) {
        output[key] = { ...obj, count: 0 };
    }

    // and subtract it from active days count
    output[key].count -= obj.count;
}

// let's remove the `key` we created earlier...
output = Object.values(output);

// here's the output
console.log(output);
```

From the sample input given, this is the result we get:

```js
[ { date: '2019-10-11', type: 'groupW', count: -2 },
  { date: '2019-10-19', type: 'groupW', count: 3 },
  { date: '2019-10-08', type: 'groupW', count: 7 },
  { date: '2019-10-19', type: 'groupC', count: 5 },
  { date: '2019-09-19', type: 'groupC', count: -3 },
  { date: '2019-09-19', type: 'groupW', count: -5 },
  { date: '2019-10-07', type: 'groupW', count: -9 },
  { date: '2019-10-05', type: 'groupW', count: -3 } ]
```

Comment: Such an easy way to solve this, I didn't think of if at all.. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you understand :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this one will be more efficient, i named the object after me cause...idn

```
        let marios = {};    
        items.day_active.forEach(d => marios[d.date+'_'+d.type] = d.count || 0);
        items.day_inactive.forEach(d => marios[d.date+'_'+d.type] =  marios[d.date+'_'+d.type] ? marios[d.date+'_'+d.type] - (d.count || 0) : (d.count || 0));
        console.log(marios);
```

The logic behind it is that we create an object and we create a property for each date present in the data sets, starting with the first terms of the formla, ending with the subtraction of the second part, and by defaulting to 0 for each appropriate case.

In the end you can iterate the properties of the object, split the string on '_' to read each propertie's date and group and create an array of the results ( if you have trouble with this let me know )